# Error about vue.js appears when try to make a gulp production

Tags: vue.js, gulp

When I'm trying to make `gulp --production` I get this error:

```
[14:27:45] Using gulpfile ~/www/webpage/gulpfile.js
[14:27:45] Starting 'all'...
[14:27:45] Starting 'task'...
[14:27:45] Starting 'js-langs'...
[14:27:45] Finished 'task' after 8.53 ms
[14:27:45] Starting 'webpack'...
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn php artisan vue-i18n:generate ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:444:11)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

It seems that there are a problem with Vue anyone know how to fix it?

I'm trying to find information about the error if I found it I will post it here too.

The lines inside the gulpfile that makes the error are this:

```
gulp.task('js-langs', shell.task([
    "php artisan vue-i18n:generate",
]));
```

If I try to make `php artisan vue-i18n:generate` in terminal I get this:

`Written to /home/lluisdev/www/webpage/resources/assets/js/lib/locales/vue-i18n-locales.generated.js`

**gulpfile**

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's trying to run `php artisan vue-i18n:generate` as a build step. Does that work if you run it directly via CLI?

Comment: Hello @ceejayoz I tried and get this result: `Written to /home/lluisdev/www/webpage/resources/assets/js/lib/locales/vue-i18n-locales.generated.js`

Comment: I edit the question, I get more specific information.

Comment: to me it lookls like you just used this before the installation of the packages in your build process thus you get the ENOENT since it can't find the files.

Comment: If I make composer install I get some problems about php version, but nothing about Vue. Also If I install the packages from package.json with npm install the same, get some warning but nothing important. @cptnk If you want we can make a chat and check step by step

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer I am actually still at work for a few hours so I probably can't chat sry. Regarding your issues with composer they should not have anything to do with the problem you facing these are packages that probably go trough npm or any other javascript packat manager. Do you by chance have a npm install or bower install within you gulp file? Try executing this earlier within your gulpfile.

Comment: I check it and no I don't have other installer inside the gulpfile. I will post a picture with all the code and you can check it @cptnk

Comment: https://github.com/martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator im pretty sure you have to install it via yarn or npm for it to work. Did you also publish the configuration like shown in the readmy of the github repo?

Comment: I read this github before post the answer haha. I'm a new computer so I will try to follow again. (Also, this works my work computer but now can't access to it, but the configuration must be good. @CPTNK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161748/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-cptnk).

Comment: Read chat when you can @cptnk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace gulp shell with exec like this :

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('js-langs', function (cb) {
  exec('php artisan vue-i18n:generate', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
});
```

And if there is some errors of version you can uninstall vue-template-compiler and reinstall it :

```
npm uninstall vue-template-compiler
npm install vue-template-compiler
```

Or you can do just :

```
npm update vue
```

Or an other way you can use this command to get you the exact version and install it for you :

```
npm uninstall vue-template-compiler & npm install "vue-template-compiler@$(npm list --depth=0 | awk '/vue@/{print substr($2, 5)}')"
```